# How to run a UWP app background completely

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I have developed a UWP [application service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) which called from a WinForms application.

So, when the WinForms application is executed, I want to run the UWP application service in the background, preferably launched hidden.

How do I launch the hidden UWP application in the background?

Comment: Did you check this article?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/09/14/uwp-application-services/

Comment: I had check this article. On debug the service, I can use 'Do not launch but debug my code when it starts' feature. Call on other app, how can it start like debug?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to run UWP apps in background like windows services run. They execute in a sandbox environment and has a sophisticated pattern of execution. You can't hide their launch, however you can run some logic of your application in background to facilitate your application like providing live tile updates, receive push notifications etc, even when your app is not running. For that you can read this article [Create and register a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) and watch [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/14) video from channel 9.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible via the iot Background App template.  You will need to have embedded mode enabled and running wherever you want to run the app, though.

Read more [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications)